# Android 1.6 Google API missing from SDK manager

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3

I'm building an application for Android 1.6 that uses Google's MapActivity. However, I can't seem to find the Google API level 4 in SDK manager. I only have Google API for levels 13 and 14.
What should I do?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried installing it via SDK manager?

Comment: That's the problem, I can't find it in the SDK manager. I can only find the level 13 and the level 14 versions in the SDK manager.
Under Android 1.6 I only have SDK platform when I should have SDK Platform and Google API.

Comment: Update your sdk tools. I faced same problem for 3.2 version

Comment: Well, it worked! Thanks a lot! Didn't think that this would be the problem because I'm working with 1.6.

Comment: How did you update your SDK then? Is there is executable to run that will update all files in current SDK for android?

Comment: Did it from within eclipse. Help->Check for updates